# 'cross-hair'-highlight of selected cell in ExpressQuantumGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, quantumgrid

I have a large grid with both many rows and many narrow columns. I want want to make it easier to see what column is selected by highlighting the current column in the same way that the current row is highlighted.

I tried using the `GetContentStyle` event, but it seems that only the selected row is repainted, so it didn't work that great...

Do anyone have an idea how to highlight the selected column in a ExpressQuantumGrid?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I have ended up with, is to force a repaint whenever the focus is moved between columns. This is *not* a solution that I like... At least it should be able to invalidate only relevant columns....

```
procedure TForm1.gridViewStylesGetContentStyle(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; var AStyle: TcxStyle);
begin
  if (AItem is TcxGridBandedColumn) and
     (Sender.Controller.FocusedItem = AItem) then
  begin
    AStyle := DataManager.cxStyleSelected
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.gridViewByGoalFocusedItemChanged(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; APrevFocusedItem,
  AFocusedItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem);
begin
  Sender.Invalidate(true);
end;
```